# Equivalence of nonlinear sigma model and the $CP^1$ model

Tags: particle-physics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

While studying the non-linear sigma model, defined by the action
$\mathcal{S} = \int dtd^2x (\partial_\mu n^a \partial^\mu n^a)$ along with the constraint $n^a n^a=1$, people often use the map $n^a = z^\dagger \sigma^a z$, where $z$ is a two-component spinor satisfying $z^\dagger z=1$. So the space of $\vec{n}$ is a two-sphere ($S^2$), while space of $z$ is a three-sphere ($S^3$). I do not understand what one achieves by going from $\vec{n}$ to $z$. Is there some properties of the theory that are more easy to see in terms of the $z$ fields ? In other words why $S^3$ is "better" than $S^2$ for studying the theory ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More precisely speaking, the theory of the O(3) vector $\vec{n}$ is **equivalent** to the theory of spinor $z$ with the U(1) gauge field $a$. They are just two descriptions of the same physical system, and no one is better than the other.

Note that the gauge field in the $CP^1$ model is crucial. Because the space of the spinor $S^3$ (unphysical)  is larger than that of the spin $S^2$ (physical), implying that the spinor description contains some redundancy, the redundancy must be "gauged away" by the U(1) gauge field. This is the standard formalism of **fractionalization**: one rewrites the physical degree of freedom (the spin $\vec{n}$) as fractionalized degree of freedom (the spinon $z$) with gauge structures. If the gauge theory is in its confined phase, then the spinons are combined into the spin, and we gain nothing from fractionalization.

However, if the gauge theory is in a deconfined phase, we can have **gauge bosons** and **deconfined spinons** as the low-energy **emergent excitations** of the spin system, which is not easy to see from the non-linear sigma model. In this case, the spin system is said to be in a **spin-liquid** phase with the **topological order**. It is further possible to condense spinon-pairs, and Higgs the U(1) gauge structure to $Z_2$, which is a different kind of topological order. So what we gain from rewriting the non-linear sigma model as the $CP^1$ theory is the description power of various topological orders in the exotic spin-liquid states.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  So in the $CP^1$ representation, the emergence of spinons can be seen very neatly. Is there any way we could have anticipated from the $\vec{n}$ representation, that there can be these spin 1/2 particles ?

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee Yes, that is the resonance valence bond (RVB) picture of the spin liquid. The RVB state is an ideal ground state wave function of spin liquid, which is a superposition of all spin-singlet dimmers. To make an excitation, one can break a dimmer which creates two dangling spins, which are two spinons, each carrying spin-1/2. Due to the RVB background, the spinons are deconfined, as they can be separated far apart by dimmer resonance. Then locally you obtain a single spinon. Of corse globally the spinon  must come in pairs, this is why the spin liquid order is topological.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee By the way, the gauge boson (emergent electromagnetic wave) also have an interpretation in the RVB picture: they are collective fluctuations of the dimmer patterns. It turns out that each dimmer covering on a lattice corresponds to a closed string configuration on the same lattice, via a mapping called transition graph. The strings are then interpreted as electric field lines, and the spinons are end points of the string, which naturally carries the gauge charge and couples to the gauge field.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It will be helpful if you can confirm whether the following picture is true.
The string of electric field lines that you mentioned are rigid in the confined phase, but in the deconfined phase they become flimsy and can fluctuate. Since the electric field can fluctuate in the deconfined phase, its conjugate gauge field (the U(1) gauge field) is frozen and the phase fluctuations in the wave function are also suppressed. Is this why the RVB  becomes a superconductor.?

Comment: Yes. Roughly speaking, RVB = resonating dimmers = fluctuating electric field lines = string-net condensation (topological order) = deconfined gauge theory. All these describes a spin liquid which is a Mott insulator, not a superconductor.The emergent U(1) gauge field also has nothing to do with the external EM field. So RVB does not become a superconductor in this way. To make a superconductor from a spin liquid, you need **doping**. The electron doped into a spin liquid will go spin-charge separation, and fractionalized to spinons and chargons. Chargon condensation leads to superconductivity.

Comment: What I had gathered from the literature is that Neel Antiferromagnet is equivalent to Mott insulator and upon hole doping Neel order is destroyed in favor of of RVB state. Did I misunderstand ?

Comment: It is wrong to say Neel antiferromagnet is equivalent to Mott insulator. Mott insulator is not a single phase of matter. Both Neel states and RVB states are Mott insulators. Neel states have symmetry breaking orders, and RVB states have topological orders. There are also featureless Mott insulators which do not have any order. You need to go through phase transitions from Neel to RVB. The phase transition can be driven by hole doping or pressure.

Comment: However "hole doping" is tricky here. By doping holes, the AF magnetic order is suppressed, which drives the system towards the disordered spin-liquid phase. But doping also introduces charge fluctuations, which destroy the "Mottness". So the resulting state is not a spin-liquid (which should be insulating), but a doped spin-liquid. Spin-liquid can not become superconducting at low temperature because it has no charge carriers. But doped spin-liquid can go superconducting at low temperature via holon condensation.

Comment: Although spin-liquids are insulating, they are still important and relevant to the theory of superconductivity because the topological order in the spin-liquid persist to the doped spin-liquid, and controls how holon can condense, which eventually affects the properties of the superconductor. So the logic is: by doping the Neel AFM (phase 1), we suppress the magnetic order and go through a phase transition to a doped spin-liquid (phase 2), which then become superconducting (phase 3) at low temperature. The RVB spin-liquid never appear in the phase diagram, but it controls the key physics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for being so elaborate. One more thing I wanted to ask is the following. In many places (i don't remember exactly where) I have seen people referring to the RVB stae as condensate of spinons. I don't understand this statement.  As I understand a spinon (actually two) appear if one of the bonds are broken. May be the clue is in the fact that in the RVB the valence bonds are being continuously broken and reconstructed ?

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee No, RVB state is not a condensate of spinons. RVB state is a deconfined state, where both spinons and visons are not condensed. Spinon condensation will lead to anti-ferromagnetic (AFM) state, and vison condensation will lead to the valence bond solid (VBS) state. I believe what people talked about is the VBS state as vison condensation.

Comment: Ok. I should have known this. We discussed in this same page that in RVB the spinons are deconfined. But in the paper "http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.58.2790" , page-2792 there is this statement that "in fact, we can think of the RVB states as a BCS condensate of spinons." I don't know what they meant by that.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee They actually mean RVB state = condensate of spinon **Cooper pairs**, but not the condensate of spinons themselves. BCS condensate of some quasiparticles actually means to condense the Cooper pairs of those quasiparticles. By such a BCS condensation, the U(1) gauge structure is Higgs down to $Z_2$, which leads to $Z_2$ topological ordered RVB spin liquid. But in the $Z_2$ spin liquid, spinons are still deconfined and not condensed.

Comment: I see. Spinon condensate would mean U(1) is completely Higgsed. Sorry for prolonging this discussion. Just one last question. Does this $Z_2$ RVB state has majorana fermions in its excitation spectrum ? I said that because when U(1) is broken down to $Z_2$, fermion number is not well defined but fermion parity is well defined so if there are fermioninc excitations, they should be majorana fermions ? I might be very naive. I just gathered some informations from various sources and trying to reconstruct things in my head to have a convincing picture of what's happening.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee There are two kinds of $Z_2$ RVB state, one called toric code, the other called double semion. The toric code state has Majorana fermions.